# Exporting a hana table having 220 million records using hana Export Command

Tags: sql, export, hana, informatica

I've a Hana table having 220 million records. (Size 12GB).
We currently use Informatica which performs a select * on my_table 
and exports a pipe separated data in  to file. This file size closens upto 100GB and takes around 1.5Hrs for the job to be executed.
Can this be achieved by export command in hana ?
And can export command be use to export the '|' separated table file to a different sever ?

Comment: What is wrong with using Informatica? Is there any issue?

Comment: We are also facing similar situation. Can we reduce informatica extraction time as 1.5 hrs is too much

Comment: You can create a SDA connection if servers are visible from each other. Instead of using a file transfer (export from source and import at destination), you can execute a direct query via SDA, etc

Comment: @Eralper
We don't have SDA.
Is there any other option ?

Comment: If the target server is SQL Server, for example, you can install related HDBODBC SAP HANA Client driver to connect to HANA databases. I did it once and documented at http://www.kodyaz.com/sap-abap/connect-sap-hana-database-from-sql-server-with-linked-server-using-odbc-connection.aspx Then you can trigger the copy process from that target server

Comment: @Eralper - Informatica also connects with ODBC driver. so I am assuming we will not have performance gain for this method

Comment: I think performance is the main issue here. I think you can do   1. if possible please do a DB table export. It may be faster than informatica.   Or 2. you can use partitioning, push down optimization since you dont have much transformations.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Informatica at all but all the rest of your requirements are covered quite well by the EXPORT command. Of course you can let HANA produce such an output file for a table. If you look at:

[SAP HANA SQL and System Views Reference - EXPORT Statement (Data Import Export)](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.03/en-US/20da0bec751910148e69c9668ea3ccb8.html)

you'll see that you can export as csv, which is pretty much a delimited text format file and and that you can choose the export target location, the separator and row delimiter.

The clauses from the documentation which you need are:

> RECORD DELIMITED BY
>
> FIELD DELIMITED BY

```
EXPORT INTO '/tmp/targetfolder/targetfile.csv' from "<schema>"."<table_name>" WITH FIELD DELIMITED BY '|' RECORD DELIMITED BY  ';';
```

This will produce a file with | separated column values and ; separated rows.

Regarding your question on the export target - this is a normal file path, so you can use any file path that is accessible on the HANA server.

Btw. depending on technical specifics of the table you're exporting and the capabilities/configuration of the HANA server containing it, export with several threads in parallel might make sense. Without laying out all details (that would be too much) you might want to play around with the number of THREADS you're using to export to speed it up. For this, you need 1 more KEYWORD --> THREADS, e.g.

```
EXPORT INTO '/tmp/targetfolder/targetfile.csv' from "<schema>"."<table_name>" WITH FIELD DELIMITED BY '|' RECORD DELIMITED BY  ';' THREADS 12;
```

Let me share the numbers of my quick and dirty example, just to give you a VERY rough idea. For a result that's useful in your context you really need to evaluate this with your table and server and fileshare.

records: ~ 72 million
csv file: 19,7 GB

1 thread  - 22:14 minutes
6 threads - 06:23 minutes
12 threads - 06:04 minutes

Answer (score 0):

EXPORT INTO will allow you to export with delimiter you want. But it is limited to filepath accessible from the HANA server. May be you could use a filesharing to put the file if you have access to the OS. On the cloud SCP, i believe you can put exported file on a blob storage (like s3). It will be the fastest method i think. But you will need special priviledges For EXPORT INTO.

Another approch to boost your export with informatica would be to use the partitioning option of informatica.(if you have it)

You can then define a session with, let's say, 10 partition points. Each ETL partition will allow you to write a custom WHERE clause on the hana source.

Let's imagine you have a customer_id or à product_id in you data.
You can use the first or the last digit of the customer_id in the where clause like
For partition 1 : right(customer_id)=0
For partition 2 : right(customer_id)=1
...
For partition 10 : right(customer_id)=9

The idea is to split the data evenly.

The write of the csv fe could be done in concurrential mode.